# Hide charts from cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that contains a drop down list of values Chart 1-4
I am attempting to run a rather simple VBA script to only show the chart selected but it is not working and I am not sure why.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("A1").Value = "Chart 1" Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Visible = False
    Else
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Visible = False
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I get an error:

[image: error]

The beginning statement is mean so that only the code will run if the value in cell A1 is changed. Also, maybe I should use a with statement?

Comment: You have some code before the Sub or after the End Sub line?

Comment: I have another sub, but nothing unusual

Comment: As SJR pointed out, I'm pretty sure it must be some code/comment or otherwise outside your Subroutines, your code as it stands seems correct (as long as you have Charts named as they are on your code)...

Comment: Wow, my idiot self commented out another sub to keep it from running while I was designing. You are both correct. Thank you.

Comment: @Xabier should propose this as an answer, and the post owner (Kevin P.) should mark is as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this as an answer as per Jon Peltier's comment.

As SJR pointed out, I'm pretty sure it must be some code/comment or otherwise outside your Subroutines, your code as it stands seems correct (as long as you have Charts named as they are on your code)...

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a procedure in a module that works your chart logic. For example:

In the worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        SetChartVisibility ActiveSheet
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in a separate module:

```
Public Sub SetChartVisibility(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    With ws
        If .Range("A1").Value = "Chart 1" Then
            .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Visible = True
            .ChartObjects("Chart 2").Visible = False
            .ChartObjects("Chart 3").Visible = False
            .ChartObjects("Chart 4").Visible = False
        Else
            .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Visible = False
            .ChartObjects("Chart 2").Visible = False
            .ChartObjects("Chart 3").Visible = False
            .ChartObjects("Chart 4").Visible = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```